# How to deploy continuous changes for database in DEV , QA , PROD environment for database in docker?

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

> (I want to know what is the best deployment practice use for database
>   changes , suppose for example we have a node.js server if any changes
>   come i deploy them by jenkins in dev if every thing goes well in DEV i
>   deploy the changes to QA and PROD . Deployment means create new image
>   for that changes and delete the previous node.js images with help of jenkins and docker as container . **How do we do that
>   for database?**)

I am working in the environment where i need database in docker environment . What i am not getting is Suppose .

I first time i have set up the docker container for postgres , I have added all the tables to the schema and all function .

**I want to know what if suppose i have to do some changes in the database .**

I have DEV , QA , PROD so first the changes goes to DEV environment  and if every thing is fine it goes to QA then PROD .

So what should be the approach for deployment the changes of docker changes . Should it be like .

1. When ever any changes come .
2. I will create new images for postgres and all the new changes to
   it manually or every time i have to add the changes in docker script
   to for the changes .

   **(I am not concern about the data persistent that i can do by data volume or host mounting . I am concern about how the new database changes should go to DEV then QA then PROD)**

**How can we do continue integration / continue deployment for postgres database?**

**For any language change** like (code change in node.js ) i every time create new docker images and delete previous images .

**But for database changes** how can i do continue integration / continue deployment for postgres database because if i delete the docker container of postgres i have to create the whole structure again for a single line change in database .

Any help will appreciated ? Any real life experience on this staff ?

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about deploying database *migrations*?

Comment: No i am taking about How to deploy continuous changes for database (postgres) in DEV , QA , PROD environment ? I have database in all three environment how can i deploy changes for then is i have to delete them all time and then create new container again.

Comment: Indeed.  But typically those changes are referred to as *[migrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration)*.  That's the keyword you should Google for.  (Though if you're not talking about migrations, please clarify what you really mean ;)

Comment: Added more information for the approach . May this will clarify the question .